# How can I get `web.Lists` to stop returning system lists?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, csom

I am writing a SharePoint CSOM application using the following package:

```
<package id="Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM" version="16.1.7618.1200" targetFramework="net45" />
```

In my SharePoint app, I do not care about system sharepoint lists. So I'm finding myself having to devise a way to ignore these lists when getting the lists for a `Web`.

For now I'm hackily just looking for lists with `Hidden` or `IsCatalog` and ignoring them, but this is not a good solution because it causes the query to have to return lists that I don't care about thus slows things down:

```
ClientContext clientContext = getClientContext(url);
Web web = clientContext.Web;
ListCollection lists = web.Lists;
clientContext.Load(lists);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (List list in lists) {
    if (list.Hidden || list.IsCatalog) {
        continue;
    }
    // Use the list 
}
```

Is there some sort of flag that I can use when querying for lists to ignore system lists so that I don't fetch unnecessary lists in my client context query?

I would figure you would use a CAML query somehow... like this:

```
<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Hidden\" /><Value Type=\"Boolean\">0</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>
```

But I don't see any CSOM method for `Web.GetLists(camlQuery)`

I found some posts around here-and-there referencing:

```
clientContext.Web.Lists.Where
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listcollection_members.aspx

But this doesn't exist in CSOM the Nuget 16.1.x package with target framework of .NET 4.5.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add to your post the code you currently use to retrieve the collection of lists?

Comment: done. it's very basic stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a filter to the server, so instead of:

```
clientContext.Load(lists);
```

Do this:

```
clientContext.Load(lists, ls=>ls.Where(l => l.Hidden == false && l.IsCatalog == false));
```

There's a fair bit of efficiency you can gain by passing off to the server your filters and specifying what to include in the response (using `include`).

Comment: My `Lists` does not have a `Where`

Comment: What nuget packages are you using?

Comment: Strange, that’s been there for as long as I can recall. 16.1.7618.1200

Comment: Have you got `using System.Collections.Linq;`?

Comment: No I'm on .NET framework 4.5 `System.Collections.Linq` Is only up to .NET 3.5. I am using `<package id="Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM" version="16.1.7618.1200" targetFramework="net45" />`

Comment: What .NET framework version are you building against @sasfrog?

Comment: i must have been missing something. it works now. confirmed here  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/0fcbcf13-c485-4e60-856c-feeab82d366a/

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza great, glad it’s working. Sorry couldn’t respond today but I did basically the same thing as the person on msdn: ran up a vanilla console app, imported the csom package and copied in your code with my change.

Comment: yeah i think it literally was the missing `using System.Linq`

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza ain’t it always the way! :)